# Creating a transition effect with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-transitions

I'm trying to create a fairly simple effect of a banner that pops out of the bottom of a flex box. I've achieved this by applying a transition on the `bottom` property of the element (e.g. starts at -50px and goes up to 0).

What I'd like to achieve is that the content takes up the entire space, and during the animation it gradually shrinks to make room for the banner (and grows back when the banner leaves).

Unfortunately, the content still shrinks to allow room for the banner even when it's "outside" the box. I guess best way to explain it is with a demo:

```js
$('#animate').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.banner').toggleClass("show");
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}

.banner {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  bottom: -60px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  background: green;
  transition: bottom 3s ease-out;
}

.banner.show {
  display: block;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
    content
  </div>
  <div>
    <div class="banner">
      hello
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="animate">animate</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gnmc99mL/3/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that works:

```js
$('#animate').on('click', function(e) {
  $('.banner').toggleClass("show");
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.content {
  flex: 1;
  background: red;
}

.banner {
  margin-bottom: -50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 128, 0, .5); /* opacity to see behind element */
  transition: margin-bottom 3s ease-out;
}

.banner.show {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">content</div>
  <div class="banner">hello</div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="animate">animate</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/gnmc99mL/5/)

---

There were two problems with the original code:

1. `flex: 1` was applied to the flex container. The `flex` property only works on flex items. So it was having no effect.
2. With `position: relative` the original space of the element is always reserved, regardless of where the element is moved. So the content section could not intrude into the banner space, because that space is never released.